# Why is the $D^0$ oscillation so different from the $K^0$ and $B^0$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, weak-interaction

I have looked for this answer into many articles and books but I am not able to figure out why $D^0\to\bar{D}^0$ is so highly suppressed if compared to the $B^0 \to \bar{B}^0$ and $K^0 \to \bar{K}^0$ diagrams. In principle, I guess that the GIM mechanism acts to the cancellation of diagrams which include vertices with opposite sign CKM factors. However, this effect should be the same for $K^0$, $B^0$ and $D^0$ mesons. I suspect then that this difference could be introduced by the different masses of quarks $c$, $b$, $s$, but I don't understand exactly how. Could anyone clarify me this difference and also cite a reference?

Comment: I suspect it is related to the lifetime: the $D^0$ is the system having the smallest lifetime (an order of magnitude w.r.t $B^0$, and several orders w.r.t $K^0$).

Comment: Good remark. Maybe the two things are related but, as mixing only depends by the mass eigenstates $|D_1>,|D_2>$ which behave different masses and lifetimes, this difference should be dictated by the off-diagonal terms in the weak interaction hamiltonian. Hence, these factors are smaller in the $D^0$ case if compared to $B^0, K^0$. My idea is to try to understand this effect with Feynman diagrams in the context of CKM formalism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I am now able to provide an answer to my question.

The *weak charged current* interaction is described by the gauge field $W_\mu^\pm$ through the interaction Lagrangian term:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_I = -\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}} (\overline{u}_L,  \overline{c}_L, \overline{t}_L) \gamma^\mu {W_\mu}^- V_\text{CKM} \begin{pmatrix}
d_L \\ 
s_L \\ 
b_L
\end{pmatrix} - \frac{g}{\sqrt{2}} (\overline{d}_L,  \overline{s}_L, \overline{b}_L) \gamma^\nu W_\nu^+ V_\text{CKM} \begin{pmatrix}
u_L \\ 
c_L \\ 
t_L
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Here, $V_\text{CKM}$ denotes the unitary Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa (CKM) matrix
\begin{equation}
V_\text{CKM} = \begin{pmatrix}
V_\text{ud} & V_\text{us} & V_\text{ub} \\ 
V_\text{cd} & V_\text{cs} & V_\text{cb} \\ 
V_\text{td} & V_\text{ts} & V_\text{tb} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
,
\end{equation}
and $u_L, c_L, t_L, d_L, s_L, b_L$ represent the left-handed projections of Dirac spinors associated to quark types. Actually, the magnitudes of each $V_\text{CKM}$ term are given by
\begin{equation}
V_\text{CKM}  \approx \begin{pmatrix}
0.97383^{+0.00024}_{-0.00023} & 0.2272^{+0.0010}_{-0.0010}  & (3.96^{+0.09}_{-0.09})\times10^{-3} \\ 
0.2271^{+0.0010}_{-0.0010} & 0.97296^{+0.00024}_{-0.00024} & (42.21^{+0.10}_{-0.80})\times10^{-3} \\ 
(8.14^{+0.32}_{-0.64})\times10^{-3} & (41.61^{+0.12}_{-0.78})\times10^{-3} & 0.999100^{+0.000034}_{-0.000034} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Moreover, it is useful to consider $V_\text{CKM}$ in the Wolfstein parametrization
\begin{equation}
V_\text{CKM} \approx \begin{pmatrix}
1-\lambda^2/2 & \lambda & A\lambda^3(\rho-i\eta) \\ 
- \lambda & 1-\lambda^2/2& A \lambda^2 \\ 
A\lambda^3(1-\rho-i\eta) & -A\lambda^2 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^4).
\end{equation}

It is possible to show that the mass difference related to the $K^0$ and $D^0$ mass eigenstates is approximated by the first order box diagram through
\begin{align}
\Delta M_K & \approx \frac{G_F^2}{4\pi} m_K f_K^2 \sum_{q=u,c,t} m_q^2 |V_\text{qs}V_\text{qd}|^2,\\
\Delta M_D & \approx \frac{G_F^2}{4\pi} m_D f_D^2 \sum_{q=d,s,b} m_q^2 |V_\text{cq}V_\text{uq}|^2,
\end{align}
where $G_F$ represents the Fermi constant, $m_K, m_D$ the masses associated to $K^0, D^0$ and $f_K,f_D$ the corresponding decay constants. These latter are generally determined from the weak decays $K^\pm \to l^\pm \nu, D^\pm \to l^\pm \nu$ and they take the values
\begin{equation}
f_{K} = (156.1 \pm 0.12) \; \text{MeV}, \qquad f_{D} = (206.7 \pm 11) \; \text{MeV}.
\end{equation}
Moreover, considering the different quark masses and the amplitudes related to the CKM matrix $V_\text{ij}$, the sum of $\Delta M_K$ results dominated by the charm quark while in $\Delta M_D$ by the strange quark term:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=u,c,t} m_q^2 |V_\text{qs}V_\text{qd}|^2 & \approx m_c^2 |V_\text{cs}V_\text{cd}|^2 \propto m_c^2 \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2),\\
\sum_{q=d,s,b} m_q^2 |V_\text{cq}V_\text{uq}|^2& \approx m_s^2 |V_\text{cs}V_\text{us}|^2 \propto m_s^2 \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2).
\end{align*}
The ratio of the mass differences $\Delta M_K$ and $\Delta M_D$ is then dominated by the $m_c, m_s$ mass term
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta M_D}{\Delta M_K} \propto \frac{m_s^2}{m_c^2}\approx 7\cdot10^{-2}
\end{equation}
which show clearly why the $D^0$ oscillation is so different from the $K^0$: **because the quark charm is much heavier (~14 times) than the quark strange**.